# image gets huge when not hovering

Tags: html, css, hover

```css
/*
color palette
dark blue-gray: #607d8b
salmon: #ff799c
lavender: #aabee0 
*/
body { /* this is a selector for <body> element (within the HTML file). Curly brackets for opening and closing. */
 background-image: url('background.jpg');
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-size: cover;
}
#wrapper { /* when we select elements with ID attribute, we use # symbol at the beginning. */
 width: 1600px;
 height: auto; /* this is temporary */
 background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.95); /* Red, Green, Blue and Opacity values. */
 margin: 30px auto; /* centering the wrapper. 1st value is margin-top and it follows clockwise as top-right-bottom-left. */
 border-radius: 6px; /* Rounding the corners */
 box-shadow: 0 16px 32px rgba(0,0,0,0.3); /* drop-shadow */
}

header {
 width: 100%;
 height: 678px;
 background-image: url('https://i.imgur.com/tjeCjbI.png');
 background-size: cover;
}
#herotext {
 float: left;
 margin-left: 10%;
 margin-top: 10%;
}
h1 {
 font-family: 'Montserrat-Extralight';
 font-weight: 300;
 color: #a92654;
 font-size: 34px;
 line-height: 46px;
}
.salmon {
 font-family: 'Montserrat-Bold';
 color: #a92654;
}
.lavender {
 font-family: 'Montserrat-Medium';
 color: #998a8f;
}
main {
 float: left; /* in a float layout, main sections should float */
}
.card {
 width: 22.5%;
 height: auto;
 float: left;
 margin-left: 2%;
 background-color: #fff;
 border-radius: 4px;
 box-shadow: 0 10px 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.3); /* initial state */
 transition: box-shadow .3s;
}

.card:hover {
 box-shadow: 0 25px 50px rgba(0,0,0,0.3); /* pointer is on the card */
}
.card img { /* it is only targeting the images within the cards */
 width:100%;
 border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;
 
}
.static {
  position:absolute;
  background: white;
}

.static:hover {
  opacity:0;
}
h2 {
 font-family: 'Roboto';
 font-weight: 300;
 font-size: 28px;
 color: rgba(0,0,0,0.54);
 text-align: center;
 margin-top: 24px;
}
h3 {
 font-family: 'Roboto';
 font-weight: 300;
 font-size: 28px;
 color: #ff799c; /* salmon */
 margin: 12px 0 12px 16px;
}
h4 {
 font-family: 'Roboto';
 font-weight: 400;
 font-size: 14px;
 color: #aabee0; /*lavender */
 line-height: 20px;
 margin: 12px 0 12px 16px;
}
p {
 font-family: 'Roboto';
 font-weight: 300;
 font-size: 14px;
 color: rgba(0,0,0,0.87); /*lavender */
 line-height: 20px;
 margin: 12px 12px 16px 16px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <head> <!-- Head contains items that are read by the Browser, and also by Search Engines, but they are hidden from the viewer; they are not directly rendered. -->
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700" rel="stylesheet">
 </head> <!-- closing tag -->
 
 <body> <!-- Body contains all the visible elements, possible to use as a background -->
  <div id="wrapper"> <!-- div defines an area -->
   <header>
    <div id="herotext">
     <h1>
 <!-- span is for exceptions in text -->    <span class="salmon">DIGITAL
     ART</span><br />
     <span class="lavender">Fine Art<br />
     Conference</span><br />
     APRIL 26-28, 2019<br />
     BILKENT, ANKARA
     </h1>
    </div>
   </header>
  
  <main>
  <h2>SPEAKERS</h2>
  <div class="card">
  <img class="static"
  src="https://i.imgur.com/jr2AoEe.jpg">
  <img class="active"
  src="https://i.imgur.com/L9K5eeh.gif" />
  <h3>Yağmur<br /> Başgül</h3>
  <h4>Dexter Sinister<br />
   <br />
  Serving Library</h4>
  <p>David is an independent graphic designer, writer and teacher in New York City. His talk and the accompanying workshop revolves around the relationship between interfaces and the concept of time.</p>

  </div>
   
  <div class="card">
  <img src="https://i.imgur.com/ZuZtSPL.jpg" />
  <h3>Alice<br /> Rawsthorn</h3>
  <h4>alicerawsthorn.com<br />
   New York Times<br />
   Frieze Magazine</h4>
  <p>Alice is a design critic and author of several books on design. She will give a talk on our constantly changing perceptions of what constitutes good and bad design, and how they are likely to evolve in the future.</p>

  </div>
   
  <div class="card">
  <img src="https://i.imgur.com/Lp8c3ib.jpg" />
  <h3>Kimon<br /> Keramidas</h3>
  <h4>kimonkeramidas.com<br />
   Draper Interdisciplinary<br />     Master's Program at NYU</h4>
  <p>Kimon is a digital media theorist and historian. He will talk about the history of interfaces through tactile and interactive displays that will stimulate new questions about how we interact with and use computers.</p>

  </div>
   
  <div class="card">
  <img src="https://i.imgur.com/eKAH6gX.jpg" />
  <h3>Rob<br /> Giampietro</h3>
  <h4>linedandunlined.com<br />
   Material Design<br />
   RISD MFA Graphic Design</h4>
  <p>From 2015 - 2017 Rob was the Creative Lead for Google's Material Design studio in New York. He will take us through the different uses of metaphors in design, particularly within the process of designing interfaces.</p>

 </div>
  
 </main>
   
   
  </div>  
 
 </body>
</html>
```

Im trying do mouse over/hover cards that plays gifs when hovering. So basic idea is images will turn into a gif when someone hovers.

The basic problem is image is HUGE when not hovering so it blocks to page. I want it in between card borders like other ones but I couldnt solve it by my self.

Im new to coding so sorry if thats a stupid thing to ask

```css
/*
color palette
dark blue-gray: #607d8b
salmon: #ff799c
lavender: #aabee0 
*/
body { /* this is a selector for <body> element (within the HTML file). Curly brackets for opening and closing. */
 background-image: url('background.jpg');
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-size: cover;
}
#wrapper { /* when we select elements with ID attribute, we use # symbol at the beginning. */
 width: 1600px;
 height: auto; /* this is temporary */
 background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.95); /* Red, Green, Blue and Opacity values. */
 margin: 30px auto; /* centering the wrapper. 1st value is margin-top and it follows clockwise as top-right-bottom-left. */
 border-radius: 6px; /* Rounding the corners */
 box-shadow: 0 16px 32px rgba(0,0,0,0.3); /* drop-shadow */
}

header {
 width: 100%;
 height: 678px;
 background-image: url('heroimg2.png');
 background-size: cover;
}
#herotext {
 float: left;
 margin-left: 10%;
 margin-top: 10%;
}
h1 {
 font-family: 'Montserrat-Extralight';
 font-weight: 300;
 color: #a92654;
 font-size: 34px;
 line-height: 46px;
}
.salmon {
 font-family: 'Montserrat-Bold';
 color: #a92654;
}
.lavender {
 font-family: 'Montserrat-Medium';
 color: #998a8f;
}
main {
 float: left; /* in a float layout, main sections should float */
}
.card {
 width: 22.5%;
 height: auto;
 float: left;
 margin-left: 2%;
 background-color: #fff;
 border-radius: 4px;
 box-shadow: 0 10px 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.3); /* initial state */
 transition: box-shadow .3s;
}

.card:hover {
 box-shadow: 0 25px 50px rgba(0,0,0,0.3); /* pointer is on the card */
}
.card img { /* it is only targeting the images within the cards */
 width:100%;
 border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;
 
}
.static {
  position:static;
  background: white;
}

.static:hover {
  opacity:0;
}
<style>
.speaker1_1 {
 height:300px;
 width:345px;
 margin:auto;
}
h2 {
 font-family: 'Roboto';
 font-weight: 300;
 font-size: 28px;
 color: rgba(0,0,0,0.54);
 text-align: center;
 margin-top: 24px;
}
h3 {
 font-family: 'Roboto';
 font-weight: 300;
 font-size: 28px;
 color: #ff799c; /* salmon */
 margin: 12px 0 12px 16px;
}
h4 {
 font-family: 'Roboto';
 font-weight: 400;
 font-size: 14px;
 color: #aabee0; /*lavender */
 line-height: 20px;
 margin: 12px 0 12px 16px;
}
p {
 font-family: 'Roboto';
 font-weight: 300;
 font-size: 14px;
 color: rgba(0,0,0,0.87); /*lavender */
 line-height: 20px;
 margin: 12px 12px 16px 16px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <head> <!-- Head contains items that are read by the Browser, and also by Search Engines, but they are hidden from the viewer; they are not directly rendered. -->
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700" rel="stylesheet">
 </head> <!-- closing tag -->
 
 <body> <!-- Body contains all the visible elements, possible to use as a background -->
  <div id="wrapper"> <!-- div defines an area -->
   <header>
    <div id="herotext">
     <h1>
 <!-- span is for exceptions in text -->    <span class="salmon">DIGITAL
     ART</span><br />
     <span class="lavender">Fine Art<br />
     Conference</span><br />
     APRIL 26-28, 2019<br />
     BILKENT, ANKARA
     </h1>
    </div>
   </header>
  
  <main>
  <h2>SPEAKERS</h2>
  <div class="card">
  <img class="static"
  src="images/speaker1_1.png">
  <img class="active"
  src="images/speaker1.gif" />
  <h3>Yağmur<br /> Başgül</h3>
  <h4>Dexter Sinister<br />
   <br />
  Serving Library</h4>
  <p>David is an independent graphic designer, writer and teacher in New York City. His talk and the accompanying workshop revolves around the relationship between interfaces and the concept of time.</p>

  </div>
   
  <div class="card">
  <img src="images/pinkguy.jpg" />
  <h3>Alice<br /> Rawsthorn</h3>
  <h4>alicerawsthorn.com<br />
   New York Times<br />
   Frieze Magazine</h4>
  <p>Alice is a design critic and author of several books on design. She will give a talk on our constantly changing perceptions of what constitutes good and bad design, and how they are likely to evolve in the future.</p>

  </div>
   
  <div class="card">
  <img src="images/taner.jpg" />
  <h3>Kimon<br /> Keramidas</h3>
  <h4>kimonkeramidas.com<br />
   Draper Interdisciplinary<br />     Master's Program at NYU</h4>
  <p>Kimon is a digital media theorist and historian. He will talk about the history of interfaces through tactile and interactive displays that will stimulate new questions about how we interact with and use computers.</p>

  </div>
   
  <div class="card">
  <img src="images/jordi.jpg" />
  <h3>Rob<br /> Giampietro</h3>
  <h4>linedandunlined.com<br />
   Material Design<br />
   RISD MFA Graphic Design</h4>
  <p>From 2015 - 2017 Rob was the Creative Lead for Google's Material Design studio in New York. He will take us through the different uses of metaphors in design, particularly within the process of designing interfaces.</p>

 </div>
  
 </main>
   
   
  </div>  
 
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi Anday, what kind of expected output you want. The images are not loading when we run code snippet. Update the <img src="">, where source is a URL. This will help to analyse the problem easily.

Comment: can you post a screenshot of problem? if you want to set custom height you can define your desired height in .card img and use object fit css property, or just use background for more browser compatibility.

Comment: Thanks for the replys:
https://imgur.com/a/xVHMarx

in first image it is without hovering.
in second one gif size is perfect.
I want it to be in the same size when I mouse over it.
I hope its clear.

Comment: Krishna I updated in the way you asked :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `position: relative;` to the CSS of `.card`. That will fix the problem with the huge images.

**Explanation:**
When you declare `.static` as `position:absolute` then `img class="static"` is taken out of the page-flow so that it is not automatically bound to the width of `<div class="card">`. With no parent-element that has `position: relative;` the css `.card img { width:100%; }` makes the images take 100% width of the `<body>`!

**Idea for improvement**: Why not use the .jpg-images as background-images for the different cards?

Comment: Thank you so much! This fixed the problem :)
and thanks for the tip. I'll also try that :)